# Typescript - Declared variable not defined when script doesn't run

Tags: angular, typescript

I declare a variable that a third party script should run and create that variable against the `window`. However, if the script doesn't run, the declared variable is considered not defined.

Example

```
declare let thirdPartyApi: any;
...
if (thirdPartyApi) {
...
```

But I get an error when doing a `falsy` check:

```
ReferenceError: thirdPartyApi is not defined
```

Is there a way to have a declared variable that is always considered defined?

Comment: No. That is why it is the keyword is `declare`. It used to tell TypeScript about something _defined_ elsewhere. Use `typeof thirdPartyApi !== "undefined"`. It's a runtime error anyway so the final part of your question is nonsensical.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thank you for clarifying. My assumption of doing a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) check would be the same of a [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `declare` keyword before initialization of variable in angular.
You can just go with the following…

```
let thirdPartyApi: any;

if (thirdPartyApi != undefined && thirdPartyApi != null) {
   //data exist in variable
}else{
   //data not exist
}
```

Comment: When I do `let thirdPartyApi: any;` and the script does run, `thirdPartyApi` is undefined.

Comment: What angular? I can't see anything in the question about it.